# Map KEY_LEFTSHIFT key in xmodmap

Tags: linux, fedora, xmodmap

At the moment. on Press of left shift key it works differently. For example on press on shift(left) + a  display '-' rather than 'A'. Shift right works as expected. I have noticed "F1" behave as shift key as well. On debugging I found there is no left shift key in xmodmap. Below are the result

```
DISPLAY=:0 xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_R (0x3e),  F1 (0x43)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1      
mod2      
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

I guess , All I need to do is to remove F1 for shift and add Shift_L there. But how would I do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting question is how `F1` instead of `Shift_L` ended up there in the first place. You can modify it to make it work again, but this misconfiguration, whereever it is on your system, should be corrected.

Put the following two lines

```
remove shift = F1
add shift = Shift_L
```

in a file, for example `~/.Xmodmap`, then execute the file through `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`. Verify with `xmodmap -pm` that the modifier table is now correct.

Alternatively, you can use `-e` to execute those expressions from the commandline (`man xmodmap` for details).